# Find the result of $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2\pi }{2^{n-1}-1}\right)}{2^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I've been trying to solve this for a while, but there's no way to obtain an exact value. Perhaps it's unable to represent the exact value in writing. Could you please provide some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Use $cos(2x)=1-2sin^2(x)$ and convert a part of it in the form $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x}$ and rest will be a geometric progression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

it is unlikely that there is an explicit evaluation for this sum. However, since $\cos(2\pi/(2^n-1))$ converges to $1$ very quickly, the sum in question will be very close to
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge3}\frac{1}{2^n}\cos\frac{2\pi}{2^{n-1}-1}&\approx \frac{1}{2^3}\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+\frac{1}{2^4}\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\frac{1}{2^5}\cos\frac{2\pi}{15}+\sum_{n\ge6}\frac{1}{2^n}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^4}\left(-1+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+\frac{1}{2^5}\left(1+\cos\frac{2\pi}{15}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{16}\left(-1+\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}\right)+\frac{1}{256}\left(9+\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{6(5-\sqrt5)}\right)\\
&\approx 0.036266...
\end{align}$$